# Encountered Error while executing UTPLSQL test from one schema to another

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

I connected to 'user1' and executed following, utplsql is installed in 'utp'. I installed utplsql framework from http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/.

```
BEGIN
     utp.utAssert.eq('test',1,1); 
END; 
/
```

Error Output

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (UTP.UTR_ERROR_OUTCOME_FK) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTRERROR", line 149
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTRERROR", line 324
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTROUTCOME", line 146
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("UTP"."UTR_OUTCOME"."RUN_ID")
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTRESULT2", line 72
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTASSERT2", line 137
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTASSERT2", line 541
ORA-06512: at "UTP.UTASSERT", line 118
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

But the

Comment: Can you update how utp.utAssert.eq looks like?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho 'utp' is schema where utplsql is installed and 'utAssert' is a package provided by utplsql while 'eq' is a utplsql comparison functionality. http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/utassert.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running `utAssert.eq` directly, you put it inside a test package, then run *that* with either `utPLSQL.test` or `utPLSQL.run`. (I recommend working through the [Getting Started](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/started.html) section of the [utPLSQL documentation](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/)).

### Define the test package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ut_simple IS
    PROCEDURE ut_setup;
    PROCEDURE ut_teardown;
    PROCEDURE ut_simple_test;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ut_simple IS
    PROCEDURE ut_setup IS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;

    PROCEDURE ut_teardown IS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;

    PROCEDURE ut_simple_test IS
    BEGIN
         utp.utAssert.eq('test',1,1); 
    END; 
END;
```

### Run the test

```
exec utp.utplsql.run ('ut_simple');
```